# Editing a Database Entry

Tags: asp.net, edit, mysql

I'm creating a website with ASP.net that, if you are logged in as an admin, you can edit the current pages text (this way I don't have to update the website all the time just for small changes, I can just edit the page myself while its online).  All the page data is stored in a SQL Database table.  Each entry is simply "ID" and "PAGECONTENT".  Now, I used a SQLDataSource to get the data and put it into a FormView on my page.  This all works.  I made a button that is only visible if I'm logged in as the site-admin.  I need to make it so when I click the button, the textlabel displaying the page content turns into a TextArea for me to edit, then I can click a "Done" button and have it update it to the Database table.  I can do the updating part, I just don't know how I'm supposed to display the text in an editable manner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called a Rich Text Editor control. This will give you a Microsoft Word style interface with a toolbar etc and it will parse the html for you that you have stored in the database.

There are lots of free ones out there. A commonly used one is the one included in the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx).

You should use [nuget](http://nuget.org/) to install the latest Ajax Control Toolkit into your project.

There are lots of tutorials out there which explain how to use this control:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+ajax+control+toolkit+htmleditor

Answer (score 1):

The POST scenario: Just like you have a button that is visible only when you're logged as the site admin, have a textarea only visible when you click the edit button and have it saved when you click the done button.

A good practice would be to have a dedicated page for the edition of your db entry unless you're working with an ajax interface. It can get complicated and unsafe to POST when changing from a detail view to an edit view and to POST again when saving. That's just an idea.

The GET-then-POST scenario: have a dedicated edit page for your db entry. Let's say: `/editpage.aspx?id=1`. Have a done button on that page that postback and save your work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_htmltextarea.asp

maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
    <script  runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   p1.InnerHtml = "<b>You wrote:</b> " & textarea1.Value
End Sub
</script>

<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
Enter some text:<br />
<textarea id="textarea1" cols="35" rows="6" runat="server" value="PUT_YOUR_TEXT_HERE_to_prepopulate_the_Data" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" OnServerClick="submit" runat="server" />
<p id="p1" runat="server" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```